# How to install dolby atmos on elementary os?

Tags: sound, audio

My laptop is a lenovo ideapad 320, and it has dolby atmos certification. On Windows (the OS that came in it), there is an app of dolby atmos to configure and equalize. There is a way to have it on elementary os?

Comment: Same question. Will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

All I can confirm, you can *play back* files encoded with Dolby Atmos on VLC 3.0 (here'a a couple of [test video files](https://www.dolby.com/us/en/guide/dolby-atmos-trailers.html)). As to the presence of Dolby Atmos in-system configuration utility in elementary OS - I seriously doubt that, because of licensing issues (elementary OS is free and Dolby Access software is a commercial product).